# Load content into a div, default one

Tags: jquery

I have a simple menu with `<ul>`s, every ul loads its content into a div onclicking it.
I'm trying to set the default content to be loaded when the visitor opens the page to be the content with the id `div1` and not all the content(div1 + div2 + div3 + div4) as it is now.
Here's my code: http://jsfiddle.net/EPvGf/
When you open the page up you can see

```
First Div
Second Div
Third Div
Fourth Div
```

loaded
I want only `First Div` to be loaded as the default content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EPvGf/1/

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#menu').on('click','a',function()
    {
        // fade out all open subcontents
        $('.pbox:visible').fadeOut();
        // fade in new selected subcontent
        $('.pbox[id='+$(this).attr('data-id')+']').fadeIn();
    }).find('a:first').click();
});
```

Really all I did was click the first `a` when the page loads. Quick and dirty.

Hide `.pbox`es on load: add to css `.pbox { display:none; }`. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EPvGf/8/

Comment: but it loads them all then fades in the first one, I want it to fade in the first one without loading the whole content first you load the page

Comment: Then add `.pbox { display:none; }` to your css.

Comment: Hi, just a little question: How can I perform the same with other div? If possible by it's ID. (e.g. I want to load content of second div by default and I have set `a` tag's ID as `ship`) http://jsfiddle.net/9kYXZ/

Comment: @hims056 `find('a:first')` is the first anchor. `find('a:eq(1)')` is the second anchor. `find('a:eq(2)')` is the third anchor, etc. To do it by id: `find('a#ship')` will select that anchor.

Answer (score 2):

Hide all divs on document ready event  and show the first one only(the default one you want to show). To show get the first one you can use the `first` method on a collection

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.pbox:visible').fadeOut();
    $('.pbox').first().fadeIn();

    //your other click event code goes here
});
```

Working sample : http://jsfiddle.net/EPvGf/6/

Comment: but it loads them all then fades in the first one, I want it to fade in the first one without loading the whole content first you load the page

Comment: @user2401856: You can update your HTML/CSS to show all /whatever you want on the page load.

Answer (score 1):

You can also add some css:

```
.pbox { display:none; }
.in { display: block; }
```

And change the html:

```
<div class="pbox in" id="div1">First Div</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#div1').fadeIn();
    $('#menu').on('click','a',function()
    {
        // fade out all open subcontents
        $('.pbox:visible').fadeOut();
        // fade in new selected subcontent
        $('.pbox[id='+$(this).attr('data-id')+']').fadeIn();
    });
});
```

And add this rule to your style:

```
.pbox {display: none;}
```

Comment: Woa 3 answers while typing mine :)